# mvvmcross WPF show user dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, mvvmcross, material-design-in-xaml

How can I show a Loading-Dialog in my MvvmCross Application?

At first, i did it like so([MvvmCross standard](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/platform/wpf/wpf-view-presenter));

```
[MvxWindowPresentation(Modal = true)]
public partial class LoadingView : MvxWindow
{
    public LoadingView () => InitializeComponent();
}
```

and whenever i needed the LoadingDialog;

```
_navigationService.Navigate<LoadingView>());
```

This looks really weird because the Modal view is a new window, but i want to achieve a overlay in my main-application.

Second, tried it with a normal User Control and the [MaterialDesignThemes nugget](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/wiki/Dialogs);

```
public partial class LoadingView : UserControl
{
    public LoadingView () => InitializeComponent();
}
```

and whenever i needed the LoadingDialog;

```
var result = await MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost.Show(new LoadingView ());
```

This doesnt work, because I think have to register the **MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.DialogHost** in the Mvx.IoCprovider before.

Comment: Did you put a `DialogHost` in your XAML?

Comment: yes, i tried it with a DialogHost declared in the User Control and set the `ProgressBar` in the DialogHost.DialogContent and i tried to write the `ProgressBar` in the UserControl.Content, both not working. It shows me `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No loaded DialogHost instances.'
everytime.`

Comment: Did you add the material design resource dictionaries to `App.xaml`?

Comment: Yeah of course, i use a lot of controls from the MaterialDesignInXaml-Toolkit

Comment: Where do you call the `Show` method? In a window event handler like `Loaded`?

Comment: in a ViewModel, but i also tried it in some Page Events.... i think it doesnt work because the Material Toolkit did not recognizing the `MvxWindowView` and the `MvxWpfView` from MvvmCross.

Comment: What does "This doesn't work" in this case mean, does it throw an exception?

Comment: yes, as i commented before `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No loaded DialogHost instances.' ` is thrown every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DialogHost` does not need to be registered. When you place a dialog host instance in XAML like below, the dialog instance will be registered automatically.

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost>
   <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
      <!-- ...dialog content -->
   <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
   <!-- ...content -->
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Internally, the dialog hosts are tracked in a static `HashSet`. A `DialogHost` instance is registered when its `Loaded` event in XAML is fired and deregistered when the `Unloaded` event occurrs, as you can see from the reference source below. The `InvalidOperationException` (`No loaded DialogHost instances.`) exception is only thrown if, there are no loaded instances of `DialogHost`.

```
private static readonly HashSet<DialogHost> LoadedInstances = new HashSet<DialogHost>();

public DialogHost()
{
   this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnLoaded);
   this.Unloaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.OnUnloaded);
   // ...
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
   DialogHost.LoadedInstances.Add(this);
}

private void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
   DialogHost.LoadedInstances.Remove(this);
}
```

In other words, the `Show` method throws an exception, because you call it in places, where the `DialogHost` control in your XAML markup is not loaded yet and did not fire the `Loaded` event, or it is already `Unloaded` again. Consequently, you have to make sure that the dialog is loaded before calling `Show`, see a similar issue [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/436).